# Exported duration times come up at time of day value in excel, any solutions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, date-time

I have the problem with a sheet I downloaded. Right now, online on its platform it displays the number correctly 0:31 (duration of a call) but when I export the list to excel for tracking, it comes up as 12:31:00 AM! It displays 0:31 on the cell but not on the fx: part. Is there a way for me to convert it to back to just 0:31 meaning mm:ss?

Comment: Does changing that column's format to time do anything? Try selecting `13:30` (2nd option for me). What format is the exported file? is it a .csv/.txt file or does it export directly  to a .xls file?

Comment: The format of the function bar can be ignored.  But the value, as interpreted by Excel, is incorrect.  With your input, the value of `0:31` is being interpreted as `31 minutes` and stored as `0.0215277777777778` (`31/24/60`).  To have Excel interpret the value correctly, your platform needs to export it with the format `h:mm:ss` (or similar); eg: `0:00:31`. An alternative is, after it has been exported, divide the value by `60` to convert from minutes to seconds; then format the cell as `mm:ss`

Comment: Of note, the `m` format will only display minutes up to 59.  If your minutes will ever be greater than that, use `[m]` or `[mm]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When data is opened in excel from some formats "csv, txt, etc" excel tries to guess what each column is.  In this case it has guessed you have hour:minute and has converted it to a decimal number (24 hours = 1) applied its default time format which is `h:mm:ss AM/PM`.

If you reformat the column to `[hh]:mm` it will display as you want it but could cause some issues later if you are doing math on it later  Since a decimal value of 0:31 (mm:ss) would be 0.000359 and a value of 0:31 (hh:mm) would be 0.021528.

Alternatively you can import the data as text depending on its original format.